# Side loading application onto windows 10 fails

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-store

I have an windows store application that sideloads fine onto a windows 8.1 laptop, but when I try to sideload it onto a windows 10 laptop I get the following error:

`0x80073cf3 the package requires minimum version 12.0.21005.1 of framework Microsoft VCLibs.120.00`

When I package the application, in the Dependencies\x64 folder I have `Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.Debug.12.00.appx` in the folder, which apparently doens't match the required dependency.  I don't have a direct reference to the missing dependency in my project, how do I find out either what is referencing that dependency, or get visual studio to package up that dependency as part of the app package, or do I need to install something on the windows 10 device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so in my case the issue turned out to be not having developer mode enabled in the O/S

Copied from here: http://www.wikihow.com/Enable-Developer-Mode-in-Windows-10

> Open the new Settings menu. In Windows 10, there is a simplified settings menu that any user can understand. Click Start >> Settings to open it. You should now see a series of 9 different categories available to you.
>
> Open the Updates & Security Settings menu. From the list given, click the “Updates & Security” option. You should now see a new page with a series of 6 different menu options down the left-hand side of the window. Click “For developers.” It should be the very last option on the bottom.
>
> Enable developer mode. You should now see a series of 3 different options with fill circles to the left of each. The top “Don’t use developer features” option should be selected by default. The bottom option is the option that you are looking for. Click to fill the circle to the left of “Developer mode.” Once you click it, you should see a little box pop up with a warning that says that installing third-party apps could expose personal information and device to security risks. If you are alright with that, go ahead and click the “Yes” button to continue. Developer mode is now enabled.